# rails has_one relationship causing problems - also white screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4, has-one

I have two models: Schedule and Project.  Schedule belongs_To Project and Project has_one schedule.  There are several problems, but i think they all have the same cause.  Here is the code for the schedules#create controller:

```
def create
            @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
            @schedule.project  = Project.find(params[:project_id])
            if @schedule.project.student_id == current_user.id
                if @schedule.save && @schedule.freelancer_accepts    
                        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created schedule."
                        redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)  
                else
                    render :action => 'new', :notice => 'Invalid Schedule'
                end
            else
                render :action => 'new', :notice => 'Schedule is invalid.'
            end
end
```

Here are the problems:

1. Even though it is a has_one relationship, I am still able to create many schedules for a single project.  This led me to change my controller to this:

   ```
   def create
       if !Schedule.where(project_id: params[:project_id]).any?
           @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
           @schedule.project  = Project.find(params[:project_id])
           if @schedule.project.student_id == current_user.id
               if @schedule.save && @schedule.freelancer_accepts     
                       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created schedule."
                       redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name) 
               else
                   render :action => 'new', :notice => 'Invalid Schedule'
               end
           else
               render :action => 'new', :notice => 'Schedule is invalid.'
           end
       else
           render :action => 'new', :notice => 'A schedule has already been created.'
       end
   end
   ```

The change was that I essentially wrapped the controller in an if that says "if a schedule exists, don't create one.  After I changed my code, I got the following problems:

1. In firefox, when I press the submit button to create a new schedule, i get this error:

   ```
   First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
   ```
2. In Safari, when I press the submit button to create a new schedule, the page turns white.  Furthermore, every time I try to go back to the page which displays the form, the page goes white.  It is very strange.

How do I fix this?  Thanks.

UPDATE:  My routes and form view might help:

routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :schedules
end
```

First part of form:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @schedule] do |f| %>
```

Comment: The code you said you changed `SchedulesController#create` to seems to be the same as the initial code you showed. What is the difference?

Comment: My mistake.  I just updated it with the code i meant to display at first.

Comment: Did your 'Invalid schedule' and 'Schedule invalid' renders work initially and do they still work?

Comment: They did at first.  I can't tell now because I can't submit the form.

Comment: And if you _just_ change your `create` code back to what it was, the submit works fine?

Comment: No.  If I change it back, its still white.  I'm not sure what's going on.  Maybe something with cookies.  But even if i restart my server and change the code back, I get a white screen.

Comment: Sorry. Been there. :-) Good luck.

Comment: alright, thanks anyway. appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this and several other problems i was having was not actually caused by the has_one relationship.  There was some type of problem with my cache.  I'm not exactly sure what it was, but by disabling the cache I was able to fix the problem.